# How I can put the required input fields in my Js code

Tags: javascript, jquery

How I can put the required fields in my `Js` code
I set `required = true` in `xml` view but it does blocker all the form
how to add required for the `js` code `jQuery`

this my code jQuery :

```
    // table  course
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var id = 0;
    var cr = 0;
      jQuery("#addcourserow").click(function() {
        id++;  
        var row = jQuery('.courserow tr').clone(true);
        var c = 1;
        row.find("input").each(function(){
          if (c === 1) {
              $(this).attr('name','course_name_'+id);     
          }
          else if (c === 2) {
              $(this).attr('name','course_duration_'+id);     
          }
          else if (c === 3) {
              $(this).attr('name','course_date_'+id);     
          }
          c++;
        });
        row.appendTo('#CourseTable');        
        return false;

});       

  $('.remove').on("click", function() {
  $(this).parents("tr").remove();
});
});
```

and this my XML

```
<!-- Course -->


<table id="CourseTable">
  <thead>
    <th>name</th>
    <th>duration</th> 

    <th>date</th> 
  </thead>
  <tr id="tr_course">
    <td><input type="text" name="course_name_1" id="course_name"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="course_duration_1" id="course_duration"/></td>
    <td><input type="date" name="course_date_1" id="course_date" /></td> 
    <td><button class="remove">Remove</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<input type="button" id="addcourserow" value="add row" />

<table class="courserow" style="display:none">
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" id="course_name" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="course_duration"/></td>
    <td><input type="date" id="course_date"/></td> 
    <td><button class="remove">Remove</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

I added here in [codepen](https://codepen.io/boubakerdev/pen/GbYqow)

Comment: *I set required = true in xml view*.....you didn't set any!! Do you want to prevent add new row if the previous row values are empty?

Comment: Try with your code: 
You can use prop to achieve this:

$("#elementId").prop("required", true); This may help

Comment: Thank you for all of you, I know prop ('required', true); but I do not know where I put in my Jquary code

Comment: @developer it's not clear which items should be required. This should be in your template or someplace else in your jQuery. If they are all required, then it needs to be adde4d in your `each()` loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please consider the following code.

```js
$(function() {
  var id = 0;
  var cr = 0;
  var names = [
    "course_name",
    "course_duration",
    "course_date"
  ];
  $("#addcourserow").click(function() {
    var row = $('#course-row-template tr').clone(true);
    id++;
    var c = 0;
    row.find("input").each(function() {
      var inpId = $(this).attr("id") + "_" + id;
      $(this).attr({
        id: inpId,
        name: names[c++] + "_" + id
      }).prop("required", true);
      console.log($(this));
    });
    row.appendTo('#CourseTable');
    return false;
  });

  $('.remove').on("click", function() {
    $(this).parents("tr").remove();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="CourseTable">
  <thead>
    <th>name</th>
    <th>duration</th>
    <th>date</th>
  </thead>
  <tr id="tr_course">
    <td><input type="text" id="course_name_0" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="course_duration_0" /></td>
    <td><input type="date" id="course_date_0" /></td>
    <td><button class="remove">Remove</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<input type="button" id="addcourserow" value="Add New Row" />

<table id="course-row-template" style="display:none">
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" id="course_name" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="course_duration" /></td>
    <td><input type="date" id="course_date" /></td>
    <td><button class="remove">Remove</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

This will ensure that each `<input>` has a unique ID and name. It also adds the required property to each of them.

Hope that helps.

Comment: hi @Twisty 
thanks for your answer, but i need different name for each input that's why i have insert condition IF (you can see in codepen[https://codepen.io/boubakerdev/pen/GbYqow]the problem I do not know or insert the required for the inputs

Comment: @developer I updated my answer. When submitting a form, if `name` attribute is absent, `id` is used. If you need name included, it is now included. Remember that `id` should be unique too.

Answer (score 0):

i find answer

```
   jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        var id = 0; 
      jQuery("#addcourserow").click(function() {
        id++;  
        var row = jQuery('.courserow tr').clone(true);
        var c = 1;
        row.find("input").each(function(){
          if (c === 1) {
              $(this).attr('name','course_name_'+id).prop("required", true);      
          }
          else if (c === 2) {
              $(this).attr('name','course_duration_'+id).prop("required", true);      
          }
          else if (c === 3) {
              $(this).attr('name','course_date_'+id).prop("required", true);      
          }
          c++;
        });
        row.appendTo('#CourseTable');        
        return false;

});       

  $('.remove').on("click", function() {
  $(this).parents("tr").remove();
});
});
```

and i add required in my Xml

```
<table id="CourseTable">
                                                        <thead>
                                                            <th>name</th>
                                                            <th>duration</th>
                                                            <th>date</th> 
                                                        </thead>
                                                      <tr id="tr_course">
                                                      <td><input type="text" name="course_name_1" id="course_name" required="required"/></td>
                                                      <td><input type="text" name="course_duration_1" id="course_duration" required="required"/></td>
                                                      <td><input type="date" name="course_date_1" id="course_date" required="required"/></td> 
                                                         <td><button class="remove">Remove</button></td>
                                                      </tr>
                                                    </table>
```